# Why my spring boot app couldn't access service of the redis node provided by sentinel but that redis node is actually healthy

Tags: windows, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel

Platform: Windows 10
JDK: 11
Command to start redis and sentinel:

```
cd PATH_TO_REDIS\redis_s6379
redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf
redis-server.exe sentinel.conf --sentinel
```

Redis client: jedis

[Detailed log](https://gist.github.com/Lysander686/0999a353091be8f0785174f4e1320f8d)

partial log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.spring.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter]: Factory method 'webMetricsFilter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'endpointHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcEndpoints' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthMvcEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthMvcEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$700f4ba6]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RedisHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/corp_name/corp_config/RedisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is mymaster master is running...
```

Comment: are you using `localhost` as address ? then use like this `bind 127.0.1.1`

Comment: @muhammedozbilicimy Are you refering "bind 127.0.0.1"? 

Where shall this command apply to ?

Comment: define in configuration file of sentinel, check this link https://rtfm.co.ua/en/redis-sentinel-bind-0-0-0-0-the-localhost-issue-and-the-announce-ip-option/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this one is to make sure your sentinel.conf file have the right config.

Add 127.0.0.1 redis-server in your host file. Use "redis-server" as the host value of redis for both the configurations of file("redis.windows.conf") and file("sentinel.conf").

The above solution is inferred from reading the source code file("Connection.java").

redis/clients/jedis/Connection.java:184

Some prerequisite:

- windows doesn't support ping the host itself using ipv4 address but mac does.